# Is this a B-measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is the function defined by: 
$f(x)=e^x $ if x is in E 
and $f(x)=e^{-x} $ 
if x is not in E  measurable?,

here f goes from R to R, and E is not member of the Borel-algebra

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the $\sigma$-algebra you're considering. If you are talking about Lebesgue measure, then $f$ is measurable as long as $E$ is Lebesgue-measurable. In fact, if $E$ is measurable, then

$$
f^{-1}([a,\infty)) = \left(E\cap [ln(a),\infty)\right) \cup \left(E^c\cap (-\infty,ln(a))\right).
$$

Since all those sets are in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, then $f$ is measurable. If $E$ is not Lebesgue measurable, then $f$ cannot be measurable (in the sense of Lebesgue).

Comment: ok, now, the inverse image of a real number under f is an element of the Borel-algebra? (considering that E is not Lebesgue measurable)

Comment: Ah, if $E$ is not measurable (wrt the algebra you consider) then it's a whole different story. But given your function, the inverse image of a single number is a set made of either 1, 2 or 0 points, so measurable. But if $E$ is not measurable, I'm afraid the function is not either...